conda build failed with error message "InvalidVersionSpec: cannot join single expression" but did not indicate the illeagal softeare name
Problem Summary
I was trying to use conda build . to build pyclone locally, I expected the building process to be successful and the building result would be generated in the directory of /root/anaconda3/conda-bld. But I got the error message as follow and the build failed.
(base) [root@DC1-09-007 pyclone]# conda build .
WARNING: No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.22
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for pyclone
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
BUILD START: ['pyclone-0.13.1-py_0_kp.tar.bz2']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /root/anaconda3/conda-bld/pyclone_1713185130739/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    _libgcc_mutex:         0.1-anaconda_defaults
    _openmp_mutex:         4.5-0_gnu                    conda-forge
    ca-certificates:       2022.9.24-h4fd8a4c_0         conda-forge
    certifi:               2019.9.11-py27_0             conda-forge
    ld_impl_linux-aarch64: 2.39-h16cd69b_1              conda-forge
    libffi:                3.2.1-h4c5d2ac_1007          conda-forge
    libgcc-ng:             7.3.0-h8e86211_5             conda-forge
    libgomp:               7.3.0-h8e86211_5             conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng:          12.2.0-hc13a102_19           conda-forge
    ncurses:               6.1-hf484d3e_1002            conda-forge
    openssl:               1.1.1g-h516909a_0            conda-forge
    pip:                   20.1.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0          conda-forge
    python:                2.7.15-h5a48372_1011_cpython conda-forge
    python_abi:            2.7-1_cp27mu                 conda-forge
    readline:              8.0-h75b48e3_0               conda-forge
    setuptools:            41.4.0-py27_0                conda-forge
    sqlite:                3.30.1-h283c62a_0            conda-forge
    tk:                    8.6.10-hed695b0_0            conda-forge
    wheel:                 0.37.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0          conda-forge
    zlib:                  1.2.11-h516909a_1006         conda-forge

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed
WARNING: failed to get install actions, retrying.  exception was: Invalid version '>=0.4,<0.4.4,': cannot join single expression
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed
ERROR: Failed to get install actions, max retries exceeded.

InvalidVersionSpec: Invalid version '>=0.4,<0.4.4,': cannot join single expression

The error message only indicates the illegal version-constraint string but doesn't point out the specific name of that illegal software dependency and my meta.yaml used for building does not contain the ">=0.4,<0.4.4," string, so I was confused where the illegal version-constraint string ">=0.4,<0.4.4," comes from and how can I find the illegal software dependency?
Steps to reproduce the problem
1. My building environment
Operating system:
(base) [root@DC1-09-007 pyclone]# uname -a
Linux DC1-09-007 4.19.90-17.ky10.aarch64 #1 SMP Sun Jun 28 14:27:40 CST 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Conda info:
(base) [root@DC1-09-007 pyclone]# conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /root/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /root/.condarc
 populated config files : /root/.condarc
          conda version : 23.7.4
    conda-build version : 3.26.1
         python version : 3.11.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=aarch64
                          __glibc=2.28=0
                          __linux=4.19.90=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /root/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /root/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-aarch64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-aarch64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-aarch64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          file:///root/anaconda3/conda-bld/linux-aarch64
                          file:///root/anaconda3/conda-bld/noarch
          package cache : /root/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /root/anaconda3/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-aarch64
             user-agent : conda/23.7.4 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.5 Linux/4.19.90-17.ky10.aarch64 kylin/V10 glibc/2.28 aau/0.4.2 c/1PlyouQjDuqe_QlHfLFYtw s/am-LeSqWTV4aG67kCTN_Lg e/3FqvZXRaW3Ga9Bman7T5gA
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


Python version: Python 3.11.5
2. Building
I am currently in the /home/fangyuan/bioconda-recipes/recipes/pyclone directory, which contains only one file meta.yaml that is used to build pyclone. The content of meta.yaml is as follow:
# This file created by conda-build 3.19.2
# meta.yaml template originally from:
# /opt/recipe, last modified Tue Jul 28 02:22:25 2020
# ------------------------------------------------

package:
    name: pyclone
    version: 0.13.1
source:
    sha256: 28386b17f5affffe78d4d67c7095f4b50b5b2751cb747d69ce530a511a964ca6
    url: https://github.com/Roth-Lab/pyclone/archive/0.13.1.tar.gz
build:
    entry_points:
        - PyClone = pyclone.cli:main
    noarch: python
    number: '0'
    script: python -m pip install . --no-deps --ignore-installed --no-cache-dir -vvv
    string: py_0_kp
requirements:
    host:
        - _libgcc_mutex 0.1
        - _openmp_mutex 4.5
        - ca-certificates 2022.9.24
        - certifi 2019.9.11
        - ld_impl_linux-aarch64 2.39
        - libffi 3.2.1
        - libgcc-ng 7.3.0
        - libgomp 7.3.0
        - libstdcxx-ng 12.2.0
        - ncurses 6.1
        - openssl 1.1.1g
        - pip 20.1.1
        - python 2.7.15
        - python_abi 2.7
        - readline 8.0
        - setuptools 41.4.0
        - sqlite 3.30.1
        - tk 8.6.10
        - wheel 0.37.1
        - zlib 1.2.11
    run:
        - matplotlib-base
        - numba
        - numpy
        - pandas
        - pydp >=0.2.4
        - python <3
        - pyyaml
        - scipy
        - seaborn
test:
    imports:
        - pyclone
about:
    description: PyClone is statistical model and software tool designed to infer
        the prevalence of point mutations in heterogeneous cancer samples. The input
        data for PyClone consists of a set read counts from a deep sequencing experiment,
        the copy number of the genomic region containing the mutation and an estimate
        of tumour content.
    home: https://github.com/Roth-Lab/pyclone/
    licence_file: LICENSE.md
    license: custom
    summary: 'PyClone: A probabilistic model for inferring clonal population structure
        from deep NGS sequencing.'
extra:
    copy_test_source_files: true
    final: true
    identifiers:
        - doi:10.1038/nmeth.2883


When I run conda build . in current directory, I get the error message in Problem summary.
What I've tried
I tried to create a new conda environment and run conda build . in that new environment, and I also tried to use a different linux aarch64 machine to run build command, but they all failed and always get the same error message.
I also find a github issue similar to my problem but that issue was marked as stale and was closed.
Ask for help
The error message only indicates the illegal version-constraint string but doesn't point out the specific name of that illegal software dependency,  how can I find out which software is illegal and fix this problem to make the build success?

I'm going to take a guess here... I think the version is invalid because of the trailing comma. I don't know which package includes that specification though. That said, Python 2.7 has been completely fully out of support for 4+ years now, so trying to build packages targeting 2.7 is probably not going to be a fun journey. You'd need to find dependency versions frozen at the time Python 2.7 was last supported and I imagine that's going to be a lot of work :-(
